# SQL sum values from many to many

Tags: mysql

There's my sql data:

```
id  name  prod_id  price
------------------------
9    A     23      4100
94   B     40      1500
94   B     36      1500
```

I would ideally like to finally have:

```
id  name  prod_id  price
------------------------
9    A     23      4100
94   B     40,36   1500
```

Here's my code I've tried using GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
    company.id,
    company.name,
    order_product.product_id,
    SUM(orders.price)
FROM
    orders
INNER JOIN users ON orders.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN order_product ON orders.id = order_product.order_id
INNER JOIN customer ON orders.customer_id = customer.id
INNER JOIN company ON customer.company_id = company.id
GROUP BY
company.id,
```

Comment: How can you have two times the same `id` in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group_concat` should do the trick

```
SELECT 
    company.id,
    company.name,
    group_concat(order_product.product_id9,
    orders.price
FROM
    orders
INNER JOIN users ON orders.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN order_product ON orders.id = order_product.order_id
INNER JOIN customer ON orders.customer_id = customer.id
INNER JOIN company ON customer.company_id = company.id
group by 
    company.id,
    company.name,
    orders.price
```